# Visual Studio error: file 'xxx.Designer.vb' could not be found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, user-controls

I'm having a minor setback. I deleted a usercontrol but visual studio is still looking for a designer file. This error is preventing me from building the program.

How can I solve this problem?

Full error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     file 'J:\VB.NET -
>   AddIn\EM_AddIn\EM_AddIn\Userforms\DocumentDisplayControl.Designer.vb'
>   could not be found    EM_AddIn    J:\VB.NET - AddIn\EM_AddIn\EM_AddIn\vbc

Comment: Open the vbproj in notepad and remote it there.

Comment: I can't find the file name in the vbproj file. I did a search on `DocumentDisplayControl.Designer.vb` but no success. Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like the designer is the missing part, so I'd be searching for just the control name, documentdisplaycontrol.vb